# Avast ye puzzlers

Tags: rhyme, visual, steganography, geography, treasure-hunt

Ahoy, mateys.

A lifetime of advent**u**re and e**x**ploration in the Caribbean has left me with quite a bit of booty, but I be an old sea dog on my way to Davy Jones' Locker.  Me doctor only gives me **9** more days.  Ye scallywags are welcome to set sail in search of it.  I'll leave me treasure map for ye buccaneers, but to know where it ends, ye need to know where it begins. **B**e sure to batten down the hatches, for dead men tell no tales.

P.S. Please also take care of **E**ugene, me parrot.

[image: 2 3 2 3 2 3]

> Thousands of leagues under the sea,
>   or over in Switzerland is where I'll be.
>
> The sum of the beast will leave you helpless
>   like the death of the monk with the Chinese Empress
>
> If you want to avoid hot lead in your mouth,
>   I'd start at naught, and go all the way South

**Hint**

> -- --. .-. ...

**Hint 2**

> Perhaps one of [my questions over at gis.SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/73295/david-starkey?tab=questions) will help point you in the right direction?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you think a clue might be forthcoming on this one?

Comment: @John Ask and ye shall receive.

Comment: So your first hint was missing a dot?

Comment: @Leppy you are correct. I checked that at least three times before adding it.  It's fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer

> The letters in bold form a url (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux9BE.jpg) for this picture:
> [image: Image from bolded letters]
>  What to do with it, I'm not sure. Perhaps overlaying onto the original text? As per @LeppyR64's suggestion -- the original picture's description is '2 3 2 3 2 3' (as of OP's most recent edit)

Comment: Looks suspiciously like the Pi symbol

Comment: I'd also try overlaying it on a map. There are some things in the verse that suggest ways of doing it, though there seems rather a lot of scope for different interpretations.

Comment: [Death of the monk with the Chinese Empress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huaiyi#Death)?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I was thinking the same. Perhaps the date is important (694) because the previous line hints at 666?

Comment: @boboquack Isn't that just what the last line of the answer suggests?

Comment: @Pat Could be. Though I'd guessed that "the sum of the beast" might mean 6+6+6=18 or something. (Not that I have any good ideas for what to do with it.)

Comment: I thought hot lead would refer to Genghis Khan but it turns out several cultures did essentially this with gold or lead.

Comment: @kaine TIL - I thought it just meant a bullet... yikes!

Comment: Take a look at the alt text for the picture.  It might be important.

Comment: Location (23.2,32.3) gives New Valley Governorate, Egypt. Not sure if that's relevant here

Comment: given the hints, I'm looking at 232323 as a six figure grid reference.  Now we just need to find the grid, ##L and Subgrid LL

Comment: Try taking each line and getting an answer that matches the 2-3-2-3-2-3 format and also fits with the [MGRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_grid_reference_system) hint.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer

> The first hint is Morse Code, translating it gives MGRS, which from the second hint, is Military Grid Reference System.
>  From the previous answer, he found the image. This is it overlaid onto the text:
>  [image: Overlaid Image]